# When debugging, how can I ask GDB to interpret the code directly from the binary, and not the source?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, elf, disassembly, bin

I need to follow the execution of some binary code I have. Since it is compiled from a version of some code I have (but **which is not the same**), GDB warns me that the source is newer than the code, and generally refuses to show me the assembly code it is running (even issuing `layout asm`). But I guess it **could** simply read and disassemble line per line the ELF it is reading. How can I achieve that?

For context: I need to get a trace of the executed binary instructions (`display/i $pc`), if possible showing the address of the current instruction, the encoding of that instruction in memory, in which function it is (like `<main+0x8>`) and the disassembly of the instruction. IF I am correct, all this information is available in the ELF file, isn't it? How can I ask GDB to print this, **starting only from the debugged ELF and not from the on-disk file**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GDB warns me that the source is newer than the code, and generally refuses to show me the assembly code it is running

Run `strip -g a.out -o a.stripped` and debug `a.stripped` -- this will remove all debug info from the binary, and GDB will have no idea what the source is (was), and will only show disassembled instructions.

Comment: Thanks! Would mind adding what section(s) should I keep to have the locations in functions (like `<main+0x1a>` and similar)? Sorry I'm not very expert of ELF

Comment: @AlessandroBertulli To keep function names, you should keep the `.symtab` and `.strtab` sections (which `strip -g` would already do).